# What should I change to get displayed permalink only of parent category?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with this code snippet. It works, but it displays all top-level parent categories permalinks, but I only want to display the permalink to the parent category of the post I am looking at.

For Example, i am on a Post Single Page and i want to make a "back" link to the category overview, so i need to get the permalink of the parent category, but not of all parent categories.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" class="back"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>Zurück zu ' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question

> For Example, i am on a Post Single Page and i want to make a "back"
>   link to the category overview, so i need to get the permalink of the
>   parent category, but not of all parent categories.

you can get the categories linked with post ids & then show first category link.

if you want to list all the categories linked with current **post/page** write <kbd>foreach</kbd> loop

<kbd>**single.php**</kbd>

```
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
   echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
}
```